# I want to refresh a Web Page every 2 secondes after moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

i want to create a Function who refresh the Page every 2 seconds after the Event mousemove, it should reset the timer while working on the Page. When moving out of the Page the Browser refresh 1 time but it should refresh every 2 seconds.
Here is the my code:

```
function autoLogoffMouseEvent() {
var idleSeconds = 2;
var idleTimer;
$(document).mousemove(function () {
  clearInterval(idleTimer);
  idleTimer = setInterval(function () {
      window.location.reload(true);
  }, 1000 * idleSeconds);
});
}
```

autoLogoffMouseEvent();`

Comment: You need to call autoLogoffMouseEvent every time after reload the page.

Comment: As per my understanding of your question , When you reload the page you loose the executed logic and get a fresh page . Its better to tell us what's the reason for that so we can help you better .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the code you've shown — it's plain JavaScript, and responds to the [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) and [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) events. Every time one of those events occurs, the timer resets and starts again. If the timer ever completes, then [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) is invoked, refreshing the page.

> In the script below, the current date-time is also written to the page after it loads so that it's easy to observe when the page is reloaded while you test it.

```html
<script type="module">

const reloadState = {
  delay: 2e3, // 2 seconds
  timerId: 0,
};

const resetReloadTimer = () => {
  clearTimeout(reloadState.timerId);

  reloadState.timerId = setTimeout(
    () => window.location.reload(),
    reloadState.delay,
  );
};

function reloadIfIdle () {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", resetReloadTimer); // keyboard
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetReloadTimer); // mouse
}

document.body.textContent = `Loaded at: ${new Date().toISOString()}`;
reloadIfIdle();

</script>
```